# Cómo busco los datos de una tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Aquí tengo mi código ya lo hice en un `input` y me busca los datos, pero al presionar el botón `buscar` no me busca, ¿por qué puede ocurrir y cómo puedo solucionarlo?.

Esto es mi código jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnBuscar").click(function () {

        // Buscar por Fecha  
        var busquedaFec = document.getElementById('txtFecUtilidad');
        var table = document.getElementById("tabla").tBodies[0];

     //   alert("Entrooooo");
        buscaaTabla = function () {     

            texto = busquedaFec.value.toLowerCase();
            var r = 0;
            while (row = table.rows[r++]) {
                if (row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) !== -1)
                    row.style.display = null;
                else
                    row.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        busquedaFec.addEventListener('keyup', buscaaTabla);
    });
});
```

Parte HTML mi código:

```
    <div class="col-md-4" style="top:-15px">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">Fecha de Utilidad</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker " id="txtFecUtilidad" />                                                                 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="top:-20px">
<!--<button onclick="jsBuscar();" class="btn btn-info btn-block" value="Buscar" >Buscar</button>--> 
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block " id="btnBuscar" type="button" value="Buscar" >Buscar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Igual me equivoco pero según lo veo, lo que haces al apretar el botón es añadir la parte del código que se encarga de la búsqueda, pero esa búsqueda no se ejecuta hasta que se produce un evento de `keyup` dentro del input es decir cuando se escribe algo. Cual es tu propósito? Que se realize la búsqueda cuando se apriete el botón con lo que hay en el input? o que se realize automáticamente a medida que se escribe?

Comment: Si saco este codigode boton $("#btnBuscar").click(function () {    //////////////  me realiza la busqueda automaticamente  a medida que se escribe  //////////////////// pero mi idea es para buscar al apretar el boton

Comment: Entonces simplemente tienes que quitar el `keyup` y poner el código de buscar fuera de la función en la que lo tienes ahora. Ahora te lo escribo en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que la busqueda se realize al apretar el boton tienes que eliminar la linea

```
busquedaFec.addEventListener('keyup', buscaaTabla);
```

y poner el código de la función `buscaaTabla` directamente dentro del listener del click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnBuscar").click(function() {

    // Buscar por Fecha  
    var busquedaFec = document.getElementById('txtFecUtilidad');
    var table = document.getElementById("tabla").tBodies[0];

    texto = busquedaFec.value.toLowerCase();
    var r = 0;
    while (row = table.rows[r++]) {
      if (row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) !== -1)
        row.style.display = null;
      else
        row.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. una consulta mas por favor esto me funciona cuando un input. Si tengo un combo al seleccionar el dato del combo y aprieto el boton buscar no me busca ..... provee con el mismo codigo  solo cambie el Id del input con su Id del Combo     //  Buscar por Ciudad

Comment: provee con este codigo      //  Buscar por Ciudad 
    $("#btnBuscar").click(function () {
    var busquedaCiu = document.getElementById('cboCiudadDes');
    var table = document.getElementById("tabla").tBodies[0];
        texto = busquedaCiu.value.toLowerCase();     
        var r = 0;
        while (row = table.rows[r++]) {
            if (row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) !== -1)
                row.style.display = null;
            else
                row.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

Comment: @MichaelPeñalozaAguirre El código lo que hace es buscar el texto que hay en el input dentro de la tabla. A que te refieres con combo?

Comment: Osea, aparte del input tengo un combo con datos desplegables y al seleccionar el dato me debe buscar con el boton buscar. no se si me explico .

Comment: Para hacer eso tienes que combinar el código. Aquí un ejemplo https://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/9v24Lqh5/. Si necesitas más aclaración deberías abrir una pregunta distinta, detallando allí un ejemplo lo más simple possible de lo que intentas conseguir con el html y el javascript.

Comment: ok muchas gracias

Comment: me voy a ponerme mas a investigar